# Root element missing after JSON to XML conversion in Apigee

Tags: apigee

When I am sending a JSON payload from an `AssignMessage` policy and after a `JSONtoXML` policy, the root element is missing.

Here's the payload in my `AssignMessage` policy:

```
<Payload contentType="application/json">        
{
    "challengeResponse":{
        "authenticationResponse":"VGVzdGluZm8=",
        "cipherKey":"VGVzdGluZm8=",
        "integrityKey":"VGVzdGluZm8="
    }
}
</Payload>
```

And Xml is

```
  <Root>

   <authenticationResponse>VGVzdGluZm8=</authenticationResponse>
  <cipherKey>VGVzdGluZm8=</cipherKey>

   <integrityKey>VGVzdGluZm8=</integrityKey>


   </Root>
```

Comment: Please share the XML that you're currently seeing. Is there an error/fault being thrown, or is the output not what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, could you let us know whether you created the JSONToXML policy in the UI?

If so, you may want to modify the policy generated by the UI so that it looks like the policy below:

```
<JSONToXML name="jsontoxml-1">        
  <DisplayName>JSONtoXML-1</DisplayName>
  <Options>
  </Options>
</JSONToXML>
```

The default configuration is explicitly setting this element:

```
<ObjectRootElementName>Root</ObjectRootElementName>
```

Using the default may get you around this.

Comment: Why root element is missing if you keep <ObjectRootElementName>Root</ObjectRootElementName> or not it is Placing Root as parent element